# Calculate area defined by matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose I have an $n$-dimensional matrix $A$. I define a region as being the set of all vectors ${\bf x}$ such that when I calculate $A.{\bf x}$ the resulting coordinates are all between 0 and 1. (or some other arbitrary bounds).

So, if $A$ were the identity matrix for example, I would get a unit cube.  Is there a way to use the matrix to get the $n$-dimensional volume of this region? What if I have two regions defined by two matrices $A$ and $B$ and I want to find the volume of their intersection?

Comment: The ratio of the hypervolumes of the unit cube and its image under $A$ is the determinant of $A$.

Comment: So in this particular case, the volume of the region you defined would be $1/\det A$, assuming that determinant is nonzero. (The intersection question is more difficult.)